# Deactivating pass from Apple wallet

Tags: android-pay, passbook, wallet

I'm trying to implement functionality which will send push notification for pass deactivation/cancellation. But I can't find any word about it in apple/android documentation. Can any one suggest a solution how to deactivate pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly deactivate or delete a pass.  But you can render it 'useless'.

When we invalidate a pass, we remove locations, beacons and the barcode from pass.json. We also remove webServiceURL and authenticationToken to remove the ability for the pass to update in the future.

However - you have to bear in mind that there may be stale versions of the pkpass bundle floating around in cyberspace.  You should ideally have your server set up to respond to web service calls if a legacy version of the pass is installed on a device and replace with the invalidated version.

Comment: Thank you. Yeap we have a back-end that handles every request from Android/IPhone/Windows phone requests. Actually it is very similar to what you have build in you PassKit solution. :)